# receive 2d pointer array in the calling function

Tags: c, data-structures

I am trying to receive a 2D pointer array in the calling function.
I called a function subsets from the main function, the subset function will be returning a 2D pointer array

```
int **subsets(int *A, int n1, int *len1) 
{
    int **arr;
    num = pow(2, n1);
    *len1 = num;
    arr = (int **) malloc(num * sizeof(int *));
    for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
    }
    return arr;
}
```

In this function I am declaring a 2D array dynamically `int **arr` and then trying to receive this return array in the main function. Note than in `*len1` I am assigning the rows value the 2D array and the column values of the 2D array will be different bases on the subsets, like for a given `array[1,2,3]` it will be like this:

```
[
    [],
    [1],
    [1, 2],
    [1, 2, 3],
    [1, 3],
    [2],
    [2, 3],
    [3],
]
```

I am basically doing the subset problem, but not able to receive the 2D return array in the main function, can somebody please tell me how to receive this 2D pointer array in a calling function.

Appreciate the response..:)

---

[update [from comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37509363/receive-2d-pointer-array-in-the-calling-function#comment62512913_37509363):]

This is how I tried to call to it from `main` function, but it's wrong:

```
int **res = subsets(A, n1, &len1); 

int i = 0, j = 0; 

for(i = 0; i < len1; i++) 
{ 
    for(j = 0; j < n1; j++) 
    { 
        printf("%d", res[i][j]);
    } 
    printf("\n"); 
}
```

As n1 (column) value will be different for each row.

Comment: "Note than in *len1..." - where exactly are we expected to note this???

Comment: Would you mind explaining what (on earth) is argument `int* A` used for?

Comment: In addition, please explain "not able to receive the 2D return array in the main function". Where exactly in the code that you provide is there any attempt to do this? Are we supposed to guess what the problem is???

Comment: You are declaring a 2D array of `num` rows and 1 columns. Is that expected? How many columns should this array have?

Comment: You're only allocating space for one integer in each row, aren't you?

Comment: barak manos : A in the input array, I am passing this to subsets function, I have not posted the complete code here, the thing I wanna know is how to receive arr in the main function, please dont bother about A, that is the input array.

Comment: column size will be reallocated like : arr[row] = realloc(arr[row], (j+1) * sizeof(int)); that is for each row, the column size will be different

Comment: "*I wanna know is how to receive arr in the main function*" by doing : `int ** ppi = subsets(...);`

Comment: If you are printing the array before the realloc as mentioned, you will get errors. You should first allocate proper size for the array before filling it in or printing contents,

Comment: "but it's wrong" - what exactly is wrong?

Comment: Look twice how much columns and rows you allocate (pass to `malloc()` as coefficient to the `sizeof` operator)  and which indexes you use to access the array's elements after, hey! If tired have a break! ;-)

Comment: the column value will be different for each row, like for row 1 it will be 1, then for row 2 it will be 2 : 1,2 , then for row 3 it will be 3: 1,2,3 
so my question is how do I print this array from the calling function with varying column sizes @barakmanos

Comment: Why not handle `n1` the same way you do with `len1`, pass its address and let the function adjust the value as needed?

Comment: @ alk, this arr will be passed to some different function and there for num rows I am assignign different column values based on the subset values, like:
1
1,2
1,2,3
2
2,3 etc..

Comment: Perhaps store the number of columns as a rows 1st value?

Comment: Or define a sentinel value (`-1` perhaps, or `INT_MIN` or `INT_MAX`) to mark the last column?

Comment: @ alk -storing the number of columns in the row as first value sounds doable, ill give it a try, thanks

Comment: I had to make too many assumptions about your code and add too many missing declarations and initializations just to make it compile. Please, be so kind to post a verifiable code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you want to achieve, but I suppose the following code may help you:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int **subsets(int A);

int main(void)
{
    int **arr = subsets(3);
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < 1 << 3; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; arr[i][j]; j++)
        {
            printf("%d", arr[i][j]);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
}

int **subsets(int A)
{
    int **arr = malloc(sizeof (int *) * (1 << A));
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 1 << A; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = malloc(sizeof (int) * A); // Can be smaller
        int *ptr = arr[i];
        int j;
        for(j = 0; j < A; j++)
        {
            if(i & (1 << j))
            {
                *ptr++ = j + 1;
            }
        }
        *ptr = 0;
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Purely for brevity, things like checking the return value of `malloc()` are omitted. Don't forget to add them.